# How to set variable context for Axiom XPath

Tags: java, xpath, axiom

I want to validate my xpath paramaters

This is my xml

```
<parent>
  <a>
    <c>name1</c>
  </a>
    <b>name2</b>
</parent>
```

Following is my java code

```
    String xmlPayload="<parent><a><c>name1</c></a><b>name2</b></parent>";
    OMElement xmlOMOBject= AXIOMUtil.stringToOM(xmlPayload);
    String key1="//a";
    String key2="/c";
    SimpleVariableContext svc=new SimpleVariableContext();
    svc.setVariableValue("part1",key1);
    svc.setVariableValue("part2",key2);

    AXIOMXPath axiomxPath = new AXIOMXPath("$part1$part2");
    axiomxPath.setVariableContext(svc);
    System.out.println(axiomxPath.selectSingleNode(xmlOMOBject));
```

but above code gives me an error.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jaxen.XPathSyntaxException: Unexpected '$'
```

How to set context variables and evaluate the axiom xpath correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`$part1$part2` is not a valid XPath expression. `concat($part1, $part2)` would be valid, but it would simply evaluate to the string `//a/c` and would not evaluate `//a/c` as an XPath expression. I guess you want something like the [`evaluate` function in EXSLT](http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate/) (and use `dyn:evaluate(concat($part1, $part2))`), but I'm not sure that Jaxen supports this function and this would still have the same effect as constructing the `AXIOMXPath` as follows:

```
AXIOMXPath axiomxPath = new AXIOMXPath(key1 + key2);
```